# Is there a way to get all styles from a doc file with Apache Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika, doc

I was parsing .doc files with POI and when text decorations came into play, it led me to Apache Tika. I can now extract text with simple text decorations like `<i></i>`, however, I would like to be able to handle more complex styles. My document contains different font sizes, subscript, superscript and so on. Is there a way to get all this information with Tika? And if not, can anyone point me to a more suitable tool to employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tika doesn't handle much more than <i> and <b> at the moment, as you've found.  Depending on the complexity of the documents, you might consider using POI directly (use Tika's parsers as examples, perhaps).  You could also ask on the tika dev list (dev@tika.apache.org) if there would be interest in adding other formatting features into Tika, or perhaps open a ticket on our [Jira site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/tika/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel).

Comment: POI was a bit hasty in sending me away, I guess. I looked into it using the Tika parsers as you suggested, and found my way through. Thank you!